# Save file on disk with name based on title of object

Tags: file, yii, slug

If in Yii 1.1.x there is some extension, to create valid file system(linux) name from object title with unique name, like a slug, but with unique name in given directory ?
I mean I want to save file on disk with name based on title of object. 
Thanks!

Actually I would like a bit more :
1) In  title of object all illigel chars(for Linux/windows OS) and space must be converted to '-'
2) if there is such file add valid counter for it , like "_45"
Maybe that not yii extension, but some php function.

Comment: have you found what you were looking for?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way - you can add object `id` to prefix of file. Then your file names always be uniqueness. For example:

1-title-first

2-title-first

3-title-second

Answer (score 0):

you can use php own `uniqueid()` to generate unique ids!

```
 $title = uniqid('wp_'); // have wp_ prefixed for title
```